# Is paypal-rest-sdk still a valid approach or should we switch to braintree?

Tags: paypal, braintree, paypal-rest-sdk

I am reading this [paypal-rest-sdk based payment integration approach from a blog](https://riptutorial.com/paypal/example/1485/node-express-server-example), but I can't find it on Paypal's official developer pages. **Question: If someone can help me link that blog's approach to a Paypal's developer page explained method, I'd appreciate**.

Instead, I see a [Braintree based payment integration approach](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/) listed on official Paypal developer page. **Question: Is this one more preferable than the previous one?** Plus, can this approach accept credit card payment (reading the doc, it seems to only support Paypal payment)

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal-Node-SDK and Checkout-NodeJS-SDK are both deprecated.

The current [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) has node samples for integrating with no SDK.

Comment: "Express Checkout via Braintree Mobile SDK is only worth using if you need a native mobile SDK" -- I am not aware of such constraint, and the example seems to apply to a web app from the official documentation. Mind elaborating it a bit?

Comment: It's not a constraint. It's a use-case. If you don't have that particular use-case, there are better things for you to use.

Comment: Does the above API support marketplace payment (i.e, I as marketplace owner, I want to disburse the payment to merchants https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/what-integration-methods-are-available-for-paypal-for-partners-ts2126